# GWT & Maven: applying code formatter

Tags: maven, code-formatting

I am working on a maven GWT project. I have generated a number of files based on the user input in .xml or other files using velocity templates before maven-compile phase. I have also written my own code formatter in XML format which formats the Java code.

How should I automate this with maven so that my generated Java files are formatted with my code formatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your formatter attached to the `process-sources` (see [this reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)). You may use the maven ant run plugin or exec plugin, depending on the complexity of your tool. You may also consider developing your own maven plugin for your tool.